# Sublime Text - File tabs has gone

Tags: tabs, sublimetext3

this question seems to be silly but I unfortunatelly used some shortcut in Sublime Text 3 and now all open files don't have tabs. 
Look on the right above DOCTYPE html

Do you know how to revert tabs?
[image]

Comment: not sure about a keyboard shortcut, but I know the command for it - `toggle_tabs`... in the sublime console `ctrl+``, enter `sublime.active_window().active_view().run_command('toggle_tabs')`

Comment: @Keith  - strange but sublime.active_window().active_view().run_command('toggle_tabs') didn't make tabs to appear. I fight with this already for over an hour :)

Comment: ah my bad, try without the `active_view().` bit :)

Comment: sublime.active_window().run_command('toggle_tabs') - also doesn't work :( Maybe there is something wrong with my editor

Comment: `window.run_command("toggle_tabs")` will do the trick. You can also select **`View -> Show Tabs`**.

Comment: window.run_command("toggle_tabs") - Pity but this time also without success. Show Tabs options doesn't work too, so perhaps my editor is broken

Comment: Now i Know what was wrong , I have plugin TabExtra that cause that problem, thx for help guys! Topic can be closed